# Confusion matrix error

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, confusion-matrix

I have been trying to do support vector machine classification in R and confusion matrix has been showing the error even after changing into factors

confusionMatrix(as.factor(yTestPred), as.factor(yTest)) # predicted/true

Error in confusionMatrix.default(as.factor(yTestPred), as.factor(yTest)) :
the data cannot have more levels than the reference

The place where I'm stuck, though both the variables are at the same level it's not working

The entire code:

##### Split train/test data

cc <- createDataPartition(classify[, 4], p=.75, list=F) # returns indices for train data
xTrain <- classify[cc, 2:4]
yTrain <- classify[cc, 4]
xTest <- classify[-cc, 2:4]
yTest <- classify[-cc, 4]

library(kernlab)
library(tidyverse)
mdl <- train(x=xTrain,y=yTrain, method='svmLinear')
print(mdl)

confusionMatrix(as.factor(mdl), as.factor(yTest))

yTest <- yTest[complete.cases(yTest),]

##### Test model on testing data

yTestPred <- predict(mdl, newdata=xTest)

##### yTestPred <- mdl %>% predict(xTest)

confusionMatrix(as.factor(yTestPred), as.factor(yTest))# predicted/true

mdl <- train(x=xTrain,y=yTrain, method = "svmLinear",
trControl = trainControl("cv", number = 5),
tuneGrid = expand.grid(C = seq(0, 2, length = 20)))

##### Plot model accuracy vs different values of Cost

plot(mdl)

##### Print the best tuning parameter C that maximises model accuracy

mdl$bestTune

##### Test model on testing data

yTestPred <- predict(mdl, newdata=xTest)
confusionMatrix(as.factor(yTestPred), as.factor(yTest)) # predicted/true

If required, I could provide the dataset as well. Could someone please help me figure this out?